# Magento - Right thumbnail image doesnt show up when linked/liked with Facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, magento

I have a Magento website and have facebook Like link on it. Clicking on it allows me to share that product on my FB wall... But it sometimes shows the right thumbnail image and description and sometimes it doesn't.

Could any one help me fix this? Is this a known bug or soemthing that I need to tweak in order to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Once you change the image in your website the image wont be changed in facebook until it scrapes it again.
To scrape it again you can use below url

```
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply..Had some problems with accessing my account. I entered the url of the products that were giving me problems. Some of them got corrected when I scraped them. But few of them returned Critical error problem. How to rectify that? Any ideaS?